# Recursive descent parsing Java - The idea of recursion

Tags: java, parsing, math, recursion, expression

I have the following assignment for university. I need help with the recursion, because I don't quite understand how the recursion is gonna work here.
I parse the Input-String, which looks something like this "((a+b)*(22+3))", into an array-list. The outcome looks like "(" "(" "a" "+" "b" ")" "*" "(" "22" "+" "3" ")" ")". Now I have the following to functions, which are supposed to parse each expressions. (TreeKnot is a binary tree with one node and two leaves, the function nextSymbol() just sets currentSymbol to the next symbol from the array-list) - Note the functions aren't finished yet, because the most simple things won't work.

```
    TreeKnot left = term(); 
    if(currentSymbol.equals("+")){ 
        nextSymbol(); 
        TreeKnot right = term();
        return new TreeKnot(left, right, "+");
    } else if(currentSymbol.equals("*")){
        nextSymbol();
        TreeKnot right = term();
        return new TreeKnot(left, right, "*"); 
    }   else {
        return left;
    }
}
```

In the next function I try to parse the term recursively, so that if a new bracket opens, I parse the expression again.

```
private TreeKnot term(){
    if(currentSymbol.contains("(")){
        nextSymbol();
        ausdr();
    }else if(currentSymbol.matches("(\\d)|([a-zA-Z])")){
        nextSymbol();
        return new Terminal(null,null,leftOver.get(symbi-1));
    }else if(currentSymbol.contains(")")){
        nextSymbol();
        ausdr();
    }
    return new TreeKnot(null,null,null);
}
```

With the expression mentioned above parsing the a+3 works fine, but then he jumps into ausdr() again and returns null, instead of jumping a step ahead. I don't want you to do my homework, but maybe somebody can lead me into the right direction. Another thing I don't understand is, how I prevent it from jumping into the "return new TreeKnot(null,null,null) case? I think, that I don't jump ahead in the right place or I'm missing some jumps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the offending bit of code

```
 }else if(currentSymbol.contains(")")){
        nextSymbol();
        ausdr();
    }
```

If you've finished a term you want to return that term. I'm not sure what the fields of `TreeKnot` are but it looks like you want to create one here.